# Callout Labels for a Negatively Logrithmically Scaled DiscretePlot3d

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

How do I place labels on top of the bar plots of my DiscretePlot3D that has a negative logarithmic scaling function?

[image: DiscretePlot3D]

```
ALPHAkSUBTRACTED = {{2.889`*^-19, 3.856`*^-17, 3.952`*^-15, 
    3.962`*^-13, 3.963`*^-11, 3.963`*^-9}, {2.889`*^-21, 3.856`*^-19, 
    3.952`*^-17, 3.962`*^-15, 3.963`*^-13, 3.963`*^-11}, {2.889`*^-23,
     3.856`*^-21, 3.952`*^-19, 3.962`*^-17, 3.963`*^-15, 
    3.963`*^-13}, {2.889`*^-25, 3.856`*^-23, 3.952`*^-21, 3.962`*^-19,
     3.963`*^-17, 3.963`*^-15}, {2.889`*^-27, 3.856`*^-25, 
    3.952`*^-23, 3.9623`*^-21, 3.963`*^-19, 
    3.963`*^-17}, {2.889`*^-29, 3.856`*^-27, 3.952`*^-25, 3.962`*^-23,
     3.963`*^-21, 3.963`*^-19}};

particleclass = 
 N[{10^-6, 10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1}] /. 
  x_?NumberQ -> ScientificForm[x, 1]

DiscretePlot3D[
   Callout[ALPHAkSUBTRACTED[[Mass, Radius]], 
     StringForm["M=`` g
    & Rad=``m", particleclass[[Mass]], particleclass[[Radius]] ], 
  Above, Frame -> True, Background -> LightGray], {Mass, 1,
      6}, {Radius, 1, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ExtentSize -> 0.5, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Mass", "Radius", 
   "Subtracted \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(k\)]\)"},
   PlotLabel -> 
  "Photophoretic Deviation between Different Radiuses and Masses of \
Particles", ImageSize -> 1000, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}]
```

I've tried using both Below and Above functions for the Callout but none of them works.

Comment: Crossposted Here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2473087

Comment: With v13.0 on a Mac, this code consistently crashed Mathematica.

Comment: On v12.2 Win7-x64, it evaluates to the graphic shown.

Comment: Using `Callout` would clutter the graph, recommend that you use `Tooltip` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the labels as a separate `Graphics3D` object created with `Text` primitives:

```
labels = Graphics3D @ 
  Table[Text[Framed[StringForm["M=``\nRad=``m", Mass, Radius], 
        FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], Background -> Opacity[.75, LightGray]], 
      {Mass, Radius, -Log@ALPHAkSUBTRACTED[[Mass, Radius]]}], 
   {Mass, 1, 6}, {Radius, 1, 6}];
```

Combine `labels` with `DiscretePlot3D[...]` using [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

```
Show[DiscretePlot3D[ALPHAkSUBTRACTED[[Mass, Radius]], {Mass, 1, 6}, {Radius, 1, 6}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    ExtentSize -> 0.5, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Mass", "Radius", "alphaK"}, 
    ImageSize -> 1000, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {-Log[#] &, Exp[-#] &}],
  labels]
```

[image]